# Can questions which have answers disappear without a trace?

Tags: support

A recent question had an answer which couldn't quite convince me. But when I wanted to have a look at it again the question seemed to have disappeared completely. In my activity log no trace of the comment I posted, and in answerer's activity log no sign of his answer.

I thought questions could only be deleted when they don't have answers yet?

Comment: You should be able to find it with your rep level. Ohh, and Congratulations on 50k.

Comment: @Kortuk - Thanks. I can't seem to find it, but since it's been deleted I'm no longer interested in it. It's just that a while ago I also suggested to somebody to delete his question, and he said he couldn't because it had an answer.

Comment: I can find the answer to this, will take me just a bit. I believe it is an answer with 2 upvotes will block deletion or a question with 2 upvotes cannot be deleted by the user. But in that case if it is a poor question moderators will honor the request with deletion for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jeff has said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/152553) you can only one-click delete when

- your question has *zero* answers
- your question has only **one** answer with *zero* score
- your question has not been recently closed ("to allow for possible reopening")

Comment: I think it was the second case, it was a recent answer. Thanks. +1 and accept.

Comment: @stevenvh, If only I received rep on meta :)

Comment: @Kortuk: I'll give you a 0-rep vote as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33478/device-to-record-phone-calls/33479#33479) was the question you're referring to, based on the fact that it was asked two hours before and answered one hour before your question here.  It was self-deleted.  The last question to be deleted before this one was two days ago.

They can't disappear without a trace, no, but they're harder to find than just scrolling through `/questions`.  Mods can find them with the `deleted:1` search option, and can view deleted answers in user profiles, but they don't show up in the ordinary listing.

Comment: That's the one. But Kortuk said I should be able to find it. I tried searching for "record phone calls", and got zero results. Would Kortuk lie to me? I hope not. Sniff.

Comment: Deleted posts don't ordinarily show up in search results.  You could find it by using your browser history, or by knowing that it's about 6 hours old and therefore between `http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33477` and `http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33482` - Your first try adjusting the URLs would be `http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33478`, which is the link you want.

Comment: @stevenvh, my mistake there. I thought you could. I forgot that was mod only. I think you can look through your questions sorted by newest looking for the answer that you did not delete but is deleted if it was your post.